# display numbers in donut chart .net c#

Tags: c#, .net, donut-chart

My stored procedure returns 3 values:

```
Apples  Lemons  Plums
20      30      50
```

I want these numbers to be visualized in a donut chart.

I tried this but it is not working the donut chart showed nothing:

```cs
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=*****;Database=*****;Trusted_Connection=True;");
SqlCommand cmdSum = new SqlCommand("*****", conn);
cmdSum.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

conn.Open();
SqlDataReader rdr = cmdSum.ExecuteReader();

while (rdr.Read())
{
    sApples = rdr["sApples"].ToString();
    sLemons = rdr["sLemons"].ToString();
    sPlums = rdr["sPlums"].ToString();
}

chart2.Series[0].XValueMember = "sApples,sLemons,sPlums";
```

[image: donut chart]

Comment: You are a little bit far from something that will work, and I will recommend some reading before doing any more. Then make a simple proof-of-concept  using static test data, and finally, you can hook this up with your db stuff. Some reading here: https://docs.textcontrol.com/textcontrol/windows-forms/article.winforms.charts.htm

Comment: Do not add xvalues as strings, add them as numbers! - Also: Did you bind the series to anything? Without binding simply use series.Points.AddX(someValue) - Also: 'Doesn't work' is not a helpful problem description..

Comment: You could watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AoVxDZe57pY

Comment: What is `chart2`?